Report Event Parameters in GA4
How do you create a report from Event Parameters in GA4?  I setup a custom event called publish_time that records when a post was published.  I can see the event firing in Realtime, and when I click on it the parameters show the dates that I am looking for, but I don't know where I can make a report out of this.  I'd like to be able to analyze traffic within specific publish date ranges.
Under Events, I can only see how many times the custom event fired, but not the details.  The same on Pages and Screens.  The event parameters are not options when customizing a report.  I tried making a custom definition, but the results come up as (not set).

I have no idea what you're talking about, but: if you're trying to do this programmatically, please include a [mre]; otherwise, if you're using the user interface, please submit your question to webapps.stackexchange.com.

There are somethings you need to confirm:

Do you set up the Custom definitions? In you case: "the parameters show the dates"

If you set it up. Do you wait another 24 hours or next day to see if the data is showing on the report? Try Explorer Report first. If data is there, you can retrieve the same data from DataAPI.


Yes I set up a custom definition on 10/23 but I still can't access the data I need outside of Realtime.

Maybe I misunderstand your question. Do you mean you can not select the custom definition in the report? Can you attach some screenshots about this and maybe we will be more clear.
